# Save form automatically rather than generating prompt to save manually

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a form that has a submit button. When I do it on my PC it works fine but on someone else's that does not have the file saved, it prompts them to save it. I was wondering if I could add something that will automatically save it to their documents folder before sending it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OL              As Object
    Dim EmailItem       As Object
    Dim Doc             As Document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Doc.Save

    With EmailItem
        .Subject = "subject"
        .Body = "BODY MESSAGE"
        .To = "email here"
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
        .Display
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set Doc = Nothing
    Set OL = Nothing
    Set EmailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really got your question. You don't want this prompt?

```
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save
```

This saves the document. If you don't want to save it, remove those lines.

Comment: Correct, I think I solved my own problem. This file will be on a network so I believe when they hit the submit button it wont prompt them to save since its already there.

Comment: Actually I have another issue, I need to the document to save in a specific location. Right now its saving over the old document and I need to to save to a specific location in order to send it in an email.